# Array issue when the length is below 5

Tags: javascript

Listing last five items in an array by using this code below worked so far, but when the array length was only 1 it started causing issues. Can I some how condition it so it doesn't cycle though when there is only one item in the array?

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("#myURL", function(getStressTestErrorInfo2) {
    if (getStressTestErrorInfo2.length >= 1) {
      var len = getStressTestErrorInfo2.length - 5;
      var data = getStressTestErrorInfo2;
      var txt = "";
      if (data.length - 1 !== undefined) {
        for (var i = len; i < len + 5; i++) {
          // dynamically generating a table-row for appending in the table.
          txt += "<tr><td>" + data[i].AlarmNo + "</td><td>" + data[i].AlarmCnt + "</td><td>" + data[i].StresstestId + "</td><td>" + data[i].StresstestRunId + "</td><td>" + data[i].Name + "</td><td>" + data[i].StackTrace + "</td><td>" + data[i].Timestamp + "</td></tr>";
        }
        if (txt != "") {
          // #table is the selector for the table element in the html
          $("#listErrorsTest2").append(txt);
        }
      }
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: `var len = getStressTestErrorInfo2.length - 5;` then you use that as an index. Did you thought about matching the logic with the condition `if (getStressTestErrorInfo2.length >= 1) {` ?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: Then you don't understand your own code...

Comment: I used 'getStressTestErrorInfo2.length >= 1' part just to make sure the array is not empty and 'var len = getStressTestErrorInfo2.length - 5' is because I wanted to list last 5 items of the array.

Comment: But your condition simply allowed every array with at least **1item**. How can't you show 5 items if you don't have that many ?

Comment: Instead of displaying the last 5 items, I reversed the array and without dealing with the length I just display first five items if there is. So for now problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach at the begging had some (stupid) flaws. Instead of showing the last  5 items I reversed the array and listed first five and added the condition

```
if (len > 5) len = 5;
```

so it did the trick.

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("#myURL", function(getStressTestErrorInfo0) {
    if (getStressTestErrorInfo0.length >= 1) {

      var data = getStressTestErrorInfo0;
      /*Function to reverse the array*/
      function reverseArr(input) {
        var ret = new Array;
        for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          ret.push(input[i]);
        }
        return ret;
      }
      var reverseData = reverseArr(data);
      var len = getStressTestErrorInfo0.length;
      var data = getStressTestErrorInfo0;
      var txt = "";
      if (len > 0) {
        if (len > 5) len = 5;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          // dynamically generating a table-row for appending in the table.
          txt += "<tr><td>" + reverseData[i].AlarmNo + "</td><td>" + reverseData[i].AlarmCnt + "</td><td>" + reverseData[i].StresstestId + "</td><td>" + reverseData[i].StresstestRunId + "</td><td>" + reverseData[i].Name + "</td><td>" + reverseData[i].StackTrace + "</td><td>" + reverseData[i].Timestamp + "</td></tr>";
        }
        if (txt != "") {
          //selector for the table element in the html
          $("#listErrors").append(txt);
        }
      }
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
if (getStressTestErrorInfo2.length >= 1) {
```

to:

```
if (getStressTestErrorInfo2.length >= 5) {
```

This way, it wont start the function, if the length is lower then 5.

Comment: Push the limit to 5 then ;) `var len = getStressTestErrorInfo2.length - 5;` will remain a problem until a lengh of 5

Comment: That's ok as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The issues you have is that no matter the size of the array, you take the size and substract 5 to it. Allowing you to take the last 5 cells of an array ... long enough. If the length is below 5, the index will be negative.

Now, you can't simply update the condition if you want to get the values of smaller arrays.

You can simply set the index to 0 if it is negative :

```
var len = getStressTestErrorInfo2.length - 5;
if (len < 0) len = 0; //Array with less than 5 values.
```

And loop until you reach the end

```
while(len < getStressTestErrorInfo2.length){ ... }
```